# How to get a list of excel cell 'name' references in vbnet?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to copy data from one excel workbook to another. Both workbooks have the same cell 'name' reference, I would like data contained in the cell references to be identical hence why im trying to list the references (to later map the values) .

Is there are a way i can list all cell references in a workbook using vbnet?

A loop perhaps?

Comment: What library are you using to reference / interface with Excel via .Net? Interop?

Comment: Yeah Im using office interop. w/ excel object library 14.0.Basically, im trying to get a list of  the cell 'name' references

Comment: Have you tried looping through the `Excel.Workbook.Names` collection? Just do a google search and you'll find plenty of examples - Here's one I found (albeit in C#) https://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/reading-named-ranges-in-excel-using-c/

Comment: Yeah looping through the main names collection seems to have worked